# SQLCMD Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Unable to
>   complete login process due to delay in opening server connection.

When I execute the first query in SQL Server 2008 R2 there was no problems but when I executed the second query there is problem shown above. My database is connected to the local PC and there is no remote connection.

Can anyone help me for finding the above remedy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Raise your timeouts ([connection](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8c87fb8-2ef2-429f-af52-20e9e0074357/changing-default-connection-timeout-value-for-sql-connection?forum=csharpgeneral) and [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142746/what-is-connect-timeout-in-sql-server-connection-string))
- Give the sql server [more memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-2017)
- Stop any heavy background processes
- Play with netlibs, turn off shared memory and tcpip+netbios turn on and vice versa

Comment: Sir i am connecting the sql server locally

Comment: @user1155613 so why? You also can connect to local sql server by tcpip, but by default it goes thru shared memory

Comment: Increasing the connection timeout worked for me thanks!

Comment: Go to the connection properties, then increased the connection timeout to 1000s worked for me

Answer (score 4):

My office switched to a MultiSubnetFailover (load-balanced) system for our SQL set-up.  Our connection manager previously had been set to OLEDB, and as it turns out OLEDB cannot accommodate `MultiSubnetFailover=True`; that's why we were getting the above error message.

As a result, we switched to an ODBC connection manager instead, and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the shared memory worked like a charm for me.

Instructions:

1. Start SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and then click Protocols for MSSQLSERVER.
3. Right-click Shared Memory, and then click Disable.
4. Click SQL Server Services, right-click SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER), and then click restart.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

We saw same error in last few days. We fixed by increasing timeout (has default 8s) on the OSQL command by adding /l switch  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/osql-utility?view=sql-server-ver16