# Remote SQL Server Connection Issues

Tags: sql-server, tcp, connection, timeout, remote-server

I am having trouble transferring data from local SQL Server (SSMS) instance to a remote server instance as well as running an SSIS package that transfers data to remote server (it works fine locally).

My local SQL Server version is 2018 and the remote version is 2014. My end goal is to be able to run an SSIS package from my local and have it transfer the data over to a table on the remote server. I am running the package with Visual Studio 2019 on my local.

I cannot find the server in the connection manager for Visual Studio or the Database Engine connection in SSMS. Also, the connection fails/times-out when I type in the name of the server and DB manually then test the connection.

I get timeout errors, but I have increased the connection timeout from 600 to 1600 and it still fails. **Do I need to add more time?**

I am starting to think that it might be permissions because I am using my work laptop or network issues possibly relating to the firewall and/or ports.

I am by no means an IT admin so a decent amount of this stuff goes over my head.

I have installed PortqryUI tool on my local machine and ran it for the remote servers IP address. The out come was "TCP port 1433 (ms-sql-s service): FILTERED portqry.exe -n  -e 1433 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000002".

I looked up what FILTERED means for a TCP port, but no one has that info it seems. They have what it means when it says UDP port is FILTERED, but not when a TCP port is FILTERED. **What does the PortqryUI tool result mean?**

I have looked at many articles to try and troubleshoot. Those include, but are not limited to, the links below:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/topic/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server-ae23c94b-b64b-5056-8b62-22e1694bb889?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
- https://intercom.help/seekwell/en/articles/3078858-connecting-to-mssql-microsoft-sql-server
- [SQLCMD Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984801/sqlcmd-unable-to-complete-login-process-due-to-delay-in-opening-server-connectio)

Also, I have tried disabling shared memory in the mmc.exe SQL Server Configuration Manager Snap-In. As of now, Shared Memory is enabled, Named Pipes is disabled, and TCP/IP is Enabled on my local machine. All 3 are enabled on the remote server.

I don't know if I need to add something to the Named Pipes in here or check whether a port is being blocked on the firewall.

I have reached out to my IT admin and he did not provide any clarification.

**Could someone possibly help me troubleshoot this?**

For example, I know how to check my permissions on the server, but I am not sure what permissions I need in order to transfer data from my local SSMS to the remote server SSMS.

My explicit permissions are "Connect SQL (Grant)" and my Effective permissions are:

ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS, ALTER ANY AVAILABILITY GROUP, ALTER ANY CONNECTION, ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL, ALTER ANY DATABASE, ALTER ANY ENDPOINT, ALTER ANY EVENT NOTIFICATION, ALTER ANY EVENT SESSION, ALTER ANY EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE, ALTER ANY EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT, ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER, ALTER ANY LOGIN, ALTER ANY SERVER AUDIT, ALTER ANY SERVER ROLE, ALTER RESOURCES, ALTER SERVER STATE, ALTER SETTINGS, ALTER TRACE, AUTHENTICATE SERVER, CONNECT ANY DATABASE, CONNECT SQL, CONTROL SERVER, CREATE ANY DATABASE, CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP, CREATE DDL EVENT NOTIFICATION, CREATE ENDPOINT, CREATE SERVER ROLE, CREATE TRACE EVENT NOTIFICATION, EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY, IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN, SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES, SHUTDOWN, UNSAFE ASSEMBLY, VIEW ANY DATABASE, VIEW ANY DEFINITION, and VIEW SERVER STATE.

I checked resource monitor on my local server for port number 1433 under Network>>>Listening Ports and the Firewall Status says "Not allowed, not restricted" for both addresses (i.e. IPv6 unspecified and IPv4 unspecified). It says the same thing on the remote server as well.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Also, if you need more info then just let me know. I can add to the body as necessary.

I apologize if I did not provide enough, but I am not proficient in this area so I thought I had enough at the time of posting this.

Comment: Filtered means the firewall is completely blocking, not even responding with a Closed message. Named Pipes and Shared memory are for servers local to your PC (on the same machine)

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface. So, if I understand you correctly, that means that I have to allow that port to get through the firewall (or ask my IT admin to do this). Is that correct?

Comment: Hello again @Charlieface. I have reached out to my IT admin again asking him to allow port 1433 for sqlserver.exe (IPv6 and IPv4) through the firewall. We will see what he says and if it fixes the issue. If it does, then can you post your comment as a solution so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: @Charlieface, I was able to get it to work with your help and my IT admin after telling him what I thought was wrong based on your recommendation. I posted an answer, but feel free to post your own and I will give you credit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 1433 was blocked by the firewall my company uses.

My IT admin unblocked it and it worked perfectly (for SSIS, Visual Studio, and SSMS).

Thank you to @Charlieface for leading me down the right path.