# Is there any solution for the Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ssms, sql-import-wizard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXSBs.png)While I'm trying to select the destination source (SQL Server Native Client 11.0) in SSMS SQL Server Import and Export Wizard I am getting bellow below-mentioned error.
**Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)**

Please help me to solve it

I tried to increase timed-out settings for the SQL server and disable shared memory in the SQL network configuration.

Comment: try to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984801/sqlcmd-unable-to-complete-login-process-due-to-delay-in-opening-server-connectio